# How can we set the font and colour in logger generated output log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can we set the font and colour in logger generated output log file ?

I am doing

```
require 'logger'
logobj = Logger.new(file)
logobj.info "Its log file."
```

I want this text in some other font and colour.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you an example of the colored gem. Just take a look!

Answer (score 5):

In order to add colors in a bash prompt, you'll have to write non-printing escape sequences.

I suggest you to read [ANSI Escape Sequences: Colours and Cursor Movement](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

A simple example could be:

```
require 'logger'
logobj = Logger.new('a_file')
logobj.info "\033[31mThis text is red."
logobj.info "\033[32mThis text is green."


# And in your bash, you'll show colors by doing:
cat a_file
```

**EDIT**

You also could use the [colored gem](https://github.com/defunkt/colored), which works like this:

```
logobj.info "Its log file.".red
```

Comment: Absolutely: `colored` gem is a must have for any logging context! :-)